# Is there any way to keep the session open after alexa timer api goes off?

Tags: api, timer, alexa-skills-kit

I would like to know if there are any possible ways or tricks where we can leave the session open for the user's input after the timer goes off because the timer API [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-timers-api-reference.html) doesn't cover it.

```
timer_request_1 = {
    "duration": "PT15S",
    "timerLabel": "Change name",
    "creationBehavior": {
        "displayExperience": {
            "visibility": "VISIBLE"
        }
    },
    "triggeringBehavior": {
        "operation": {
            "type": "ANNOUNCE", 
            "textToAnnounce": [
                {
                    "locale": "en-US",
                    "text": "Would you like to proceed with the x task?"
                }
            ]
        },
        "notificationConfig": {
            "playAudible": False 
        }
    }
}

REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = ["alexa::alerts:timers:skill:readwrite"]

class TimerIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("TimerIntent")(handler_input)
    
    def handle(self, handler_input):

        permissions = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.permissions
        if not (permissions and permissions.consent_token):
            return (
                handler_input.response_builder
                .speak("Please give permissions to set timers using the alexa app.")
                .set_card(
                    AskForPermissionsConsentCard(permissions=REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
                )
                .response
            )
        
        timer_service = handler_input.service_client_factory.get_timer_management_service()                        
        timer_response = timer_service.create_timer(timer_request)
        
        if str(timer_response.status) == "Status.ON":
            session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes
            if not session_attr:
                session_attr['lastTimerId'] = timer_response.id
                speech_text = 'Your 40 minutes timer has started!.'
                return (
                    handler_input.response_builder
                    .speak(speech_text)
                    .response
                    .ask("Would you like to proceed x task?")
                    )
        else:
            speech_text = 'Timer did not start'

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speech_text)
            .response
        )
```

I tried by adding a `return .ask()` but I got `'Response' object has no attribute 'ask'` error.

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

You use `response` to get the response from `response_builder` so you should place all `speak`, `ask` etc. builder methods before `response`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is it possible to open the season only after the timer goes off?

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep the session alive is to not send "shouldEndSession". This will not let the session close. But this will not be approved if you go for certification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How about if we want to only open the session after the timer goes off? is that possible and get certified?

Comment: shouldEndSession is only for an explicit end. If you don't send it, the skill can still time out before the timer ends. As noted when this was brought to Alexa Office Hours yesterday, you can have the timer announcement prompt the customer to open the skill again, or you can have the timer launch a custom task that takes the customer back into the skill.

Comment: Hi @LetMyPeopleCode Can you elaborate a little more about what you mean by explicit end? As well as, would I not get a certificate if not send ShouldEndSession? I did try custom task but even when you use that it asks the user whether wants to {continuewithskillname} w/o opening the session afterwards nor even reads the confirmation text https://github.com/danieldhz/Alexa_Timer/blob/master/lambda/lambda_function.py. As well as, in the office, we discussed how to keep the session on "throughout" the timer, which now that I think about it should never be done. So is there any way to open After

Comment: Explicit end... i.e. you're explicitly telling Alexa to end the session. Like saying "I'm done now." As opposed to the customer quitting or just things timing out. As for the other question... I don't believe there is and I can't focus on tracking down a more definitive answer right now.